# AKS with managed Prometheus not showing windows pod metrics

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, azure-aks

I have a new AKS cluster which I'm trying to use managed Prometheus to monitor some windows pods.

I have followed the guide here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/prometheus-metrics-enable?tabs=azure-portal#enable-windows-metrics-collection to enable windows monitoring but using the managed grafana I'm not seeing anything on the windows dashboards, e.g.:

[image]

But from the guide the section that has "check this to make sure its all working" I'm getting successful results.

The one thing I have noticed is from prometheus I see this:

[image]

Which I assume is part of the reason why I'm not getting anything in grafana.

Question is how do I go about debugging what I've missed as I believe I've done everything required in the docs.